# How can I get a bit output using xxd with user input

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to get the bit of a string that was inputted but nothing is showing.
I'm typing in `xxd -b ./string "carlo"`
string file is:

```
string="$1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading the xxd man pages to help you understand how xxd works

https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd

I'm also not 100% sure what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to see a bitwise representation of the string "carlo"?  In that case does `echo "carlo" | xxd -b` work for you?  The command you are running appears to be taking in the content of the file named "string" and saving it to a new file named "carlo"

From the man pages:

```
SYNOPSIS
   xxd -h[elp]
   xxd [options] [infile [outfile]]
   xxd -r[evert] [options] [infile [outfile]]
```

Your [options] is `-b`

Your [infile] is `./string`

Your [outfile] is `"carlo"`

Comment: Yeah I am trying to get the bitwise representation of the string that I am passing in to the string file. I did not mean for "carlo" to be my outfile, I just wanted carlo to be the input to string.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by "input to string."  `./string` is just a file that you are getting a binary representation of.  It has no "inputs" or "outputs"